# Call a webapi whenever an item is added to an Azure Service Bus queue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a way to invoke a .netcore web api method whenever a message is added to an Azure Servicebus queue ? I would like to implement this without any sort of timer based polling.

I can manually call an api endpoint to process the queue like this:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessQue()
        {
            List<string> reList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                // Register a OnMessage callback
                queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
                    async (message, token) =>
                    {
                        // Process the message
                        reList.Add($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SequenceNumber} Body:{message.GetBody<string>()}");

                        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
                        // This can be done only if the queueClient is opened in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode.
                        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.LockToken);
                    },
                    new RegisterHandlerOptions() {MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, AutoComplete = false});
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Exception: {exception.Message}");
            }

            return Ok(reList);
        }
```

I am looking for a way that this method will fire automatically when a message is added to a queue. Azure functions is probably the right way to do this but I havent been able to connect an azure function to a servicebus queue.

Any suggestions, advise, pocket lint, anything is much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Messages added on the broker. You don't control the broker. If broker would support callbacks, that would be a different thing. Frankly, I don't understand what are you trying to solve. The code snippet above doesn't make a lot of sense as it's registering a message pump (to receive messages) in a WebAPI action...You could do it with an intermediate step (functions as you've mentioned), but that means you'd be having a higher cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Functions for invoking the web api. You need to set the Azure Servicebus queue as the binding. You can get more information on how to use [Azure Functions Service Bus bindings on MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus)